# Google Cloud PubSub re-delivering message before ack-deadline even when exactly once is enabled

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a PubSub subscription with Exactly once delivery and exponential retries enabled. The exponential retry has min backoff as 10 sec and max back off as 600 sec. The ack deadline is set to 60 sec (and also to 120 sec in second test).

I have a subscriber reading from this subscription

```java
 Subscriber subscriber = pubSubTemplate.subscribe("projects/PROJECT_ID/subscriptions/sushil-exactly-once-topic-sub", (basicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage -> {
        PubsubMessage message = basicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage.getPubsubMessage();
        String data = message.getData().toStringUtf8();
        String id = message.getMessageId();
        log.info("Message {}", data);
      }));
      subscriber.startAsync();
```

I'm forcefully not `acking` my message to simulate real-world failures. What I'm seeing is that first re-delivery is always happening around `23-26 sec` consistently across multiple tests.

```
2023-07-13T11:22:04.967+05:30  INFO 66438 --- [sub-subscriber1] c.w.e.PubSubStandaloneConfiguration      : Message Message-1
2023-07-13T11:22:30.715+05:30  INFO 66438 --- [sub-subscriber1] c.w.e.PubSubStandaloneConfiguration      : Message Message-1
2023-07-13T11:23:47.788+05:30  INFO 66438 --- [sub-subscriber2] c.w.e.PubSubStandaloneConfiguration      : Message Message-1
```

Post first re-delivery all the deliveries are happening after 60 secs are exhausted.

I have tried this with both `spring-integration` and basic consumer (the code above) and the behaviour is consistent.

My understanding is that even first re-delivery should happen after 60 sec.

I just wanted to check if this is correct behaviour and my understanding is flawed or is there some bug ?

Comment: Hi @kaysush, Are you calculating the 23-26 seconds time after ack deadline ?<br>

Comment: @DhirajSingh No. I'm calculating 23-26 secs from first delivery and then re-delivery. You can check the attached logs for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Backoff time is the time for which Pubsub will wait before re-sending the message. If in the consecutive deliveries your message is not acked this backoff time will gradually increase (to max 600sec). This is mentioned in the google documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#exponential_backoff).

I replicated this scenario at my end, and this is how it worked. Considering your setup with ack deadline 60sec, min backoff 10sec. After your 1st message is not acked (60 sec ack deadline passed) pubsub will wait for min 10 sec to re-deliver the message. Please note it can sometimes be more than the provided min backoff time. Now, if the msg is not  acked, again pubsub will redeliver with a wait time more than 10 secs.

Comment: I get that part, however my first re-delivery is happening before the ack-deadline is getting expired.

Comment: Hi @kaysush, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set ackDeadline on the subscriber options?

I just ran into the same issue and went to look at the source code.
It seems each language has a default value which is enforced when subscribing even with default config, overriding the bucket configuration.

e.g.
For nodejs the subscriber will auto set it to 10 seconds.

See https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/main/src/subscriber.ts#L356

For C# the subscriber will auto set it to 60 seconds.

See https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SubscriberClient.Settings.cs#L66 and https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SubscriberClient.cs#L77

Comment: I forgot to update this thread, but turns out it was a bug in the version of Java library that I was using and got resolved by upgrading to a new version.